# Pen Computing App Development in Windows Phone

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mobile, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, handwriting-recognition

I wanted to make an app in windows phone that takes in pen-computing input. Is there existing code infrastructure (templates and such) in the Windows Phone API that is available to the Windows Phone developer?

What I mean by pen-computing input is hand-writing input by users' fingers, giving us input like this:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unluckily for Windows Phone 8 and Windows phone 8.1 [InkManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.inking.inkmanager.aspx) class is not supported currently, so capturing handwritten input aint possible.
Though it works for windows 8 and 8.1 store apps which you can implement through [Tutorial1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh974457.aspx) and [Tutorial2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn792131.aspx)

If you are focusing Windows phone would suggest to make app for Windows 10. They have release a better version of InkCanvas which is better than InkManager and works both store and phone apps being UWP. Check out this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt590975.aspx) for details on InkCanvas